# Watir question regarding selecting a hidden dropdown

Tags: ruby, watir

I have two dropdowns, the second dropdown does not show until a choice is made from the first one. Using watir, i can select the first dropdown, and when i watch it, the second one becomes active, but it cannot select it. i just tried the regular select_list using name and id. Here is the code for the second drop down.

```
<td>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="list" id="list">
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript"></script>
<select>
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</td>
```

I've also notice the value for the hidden field change as i select different options.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Please post your Watir code and error messages, if any. How did you access select list with id, when it does not have one?

Comment: Your question is incomplete.So please,provide your main ruby as well as html and error

Answer (score 1):

The way that I usually access drop down lists is by using this string:

```
@browser.select_list(:name, "list").set("3")
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

I usually select hidden dropdowns this way

```
ie.hidden(:name=>"list").value='2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
browserObj = Watir::Browser.new
browserObj.goto('you html in browser')
//browserObj.hidden(:id,"list").value
browserObj.select_list(:name, "list").select_value('2')
```